# SQL: How to get all rows that it's columns meet a certain condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

Could you please help me to do this in a single query?

Supose we have this table TRANSACTIONS

```
TRASACTIONS

ID    NAME      TYPE    CREDIT    DEBIT
1     Xavier    1       99        0
2     Andy      1       101       0
3     Sebas     2       0         99
4     Tyrel     2       0         101
```

I would like to get all rows that meet the following condition:
If TYPE = 1, CREDIT > 100. ELSE IF TYPE = 2, DEBIT > 100.

The table result should be:

```
TRASACTIONS

ID    NAME      TYPE    CREDIT    DEBIT
2     Andy      1       101       0
4     Tyrel     2       0         101
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express this using `or`:

```
where (type = 1 and credit > 100) or
      (type = 2 and debit > 100)
```